# Failed to load resource with Websocket application

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I'm using Spring Boot and Tomcat 7 to create a webapplication with Websockets using STOMP and sockJS. The following is the class with my request mapping:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following errors in my console on the webpage:

```
Opening Web Socket...
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)             http://localhost:8080/WarTest/hello/info
Whoops! Lost connection to undefined
Opening Web Socket...
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)             http://localhost:8080/WarTest/hello/info
Whoops! Lost connection to undefined
```

hello is my package with most of the code, but I'm not sure what the "info" directory that is causing the error is. Is there anyone out there who might be able to help me out?

EDIT:
Here is my Javascript client code:

```
function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS('/WarTest/hello');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            setConnected(true);
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
                showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
            });
        });
    }

    function disconnect() {
        stompClient.disconnect();
        setConnected(false);
        console.log("Disconnected");
    }

    function sendName() {
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': name }));
    }

    function showGreeting(message) {
        var response = document.getElementById('response');
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        response.appendChild(p);
```

And my websocketconfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

EDIT:

WebInitializer.java

```
public class WebInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)    {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

EDIT2:

WebsocketConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app").enableSimpleBroker("/queue","/topic");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

EDIT3:

I get this when I start it straight from the IDE using `SockJS('http://localhost:8080/WarTest/hello'):`

```
Opening Web Socket... stomp.js:130
Web Socket Opened... stomp.js:130
>>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

stomp.js:130
<<< CONNECTED
heart-beat:0,0
version:1.1

stomp.js:130
connected to server undefined stomp.js:130
Connected: CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:0,0

(index):23
>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/topic/greetings
```

However, when I deploy as WAR to Tomcat, I get the error where the URL/info is not found.

Comment: You should show the endpoint configuration and client code for connection. Looks like you use wrong `URL` to connect to WebSocket endpoint

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Artem! I've added some of my implementation. Let me know if this helps or if there's anything else I can add!

Comment: Show, please, how do you register the `DispatcherServlet`? Or you just wanted to do that, but show `WebSocketConfig` one more time...

Comment: Sorry, had them mixed up. Updated both WebsocketConfig and WebInitializer

Comment: Can you show the URL, which you use to get access to the page with WebSocket client code? Is that a page from the same WAR ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should add the application context to the `SockJS` constructor. From Spring Reference Manual:

```
var socket = new SockJS("/spring-websocket-portfolio/portfolio");
```

where the configuration is:

```
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
            .enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
    }

    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/portfolio").withSockJS();
    }
```

But WebApp is deployed under context `/spring-websocket-portfolio`.

**UPDATE**

Would be great, if you show the URL for your webapp. Assume you should use **full** URL for WebSocket endpoint from `SockJS` constructor:

```
var socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/WarTest/hello");
```

**UPDATE2**

You should several things:

1. The webapp is deployed under some context. I guess, in your case it is `WarTest`. Tipically is a WAR name without `.war` extension.
2. Spring MVC application is based on `DispatcherServlet`, which is registered in the webapp config (`web.xml` or `WebApplicationInitializer`) with some mapping. E.g. `/spring`
3. Each service (`Controller`, its methods, or WebSocket endpoint) is registered under some URI path. In your case it is `/hello`.

So, you full SockJS URL should be like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/WarTest/spring/hello
```

If you specify the `port` correctly, though.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry but what do you mean by deploying under the context "/spring-websocket-portfolio"? Do I need to change the name of my package? (currently "hello"). Do I need to change other references of "hello" to "portfolio" as well?

Comment: Of course no: it was just a sample. How do you access to your app over HTTP - `http://localhost:8080/...`? Or how do you call the `index` page from browser ?

Comment: Hi Artem, my application now works when I run it from Eclipse but I get the same error as before when I try to deploy as a war to Tomcat. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've edited my question to reflect my new issue, although it is basically of the same nature just that I am now deploying as a WAR to Tomcat rather than using Eclipse to start the standalone instance.

Comment: I tried using the full URL, but still ended up with the same error. Do you know what the /info that the error refers to is? Also, I'm learning a lot from your help and appreciate you putting in this time.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. So would the "/spring" in my case be "/app"? How would I find what that was?

Comment: I've added my web initializer to the question.